# VBA Copy and append

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying include a copy and append to new worksheet BEFORE delete entire row and add extra row to bottom. This is what I have so far

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim SrchRng As Range
    Dim SrchStr As String
    On Error GoTo Err_Execute


    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B5000")
    SrchStr = InputBox("Please Enter Number")
    For Each cell In SrchRng
        If cell.Value = SrchStr Then cell.EntireRow.Delete
    Next cell
    Range("C5499:F5499").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C5499:F5500"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("C5499:F5500").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
   Exit Sub
Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

Comment: don't quite understand what you're trying to do with `Range("C5499:F5499").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C5499:F5500"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("C5499:F5500").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select`

Comment: this copies the formula to the next row so there is always 5000 rows in the sheet. every time you delete a row, it adds one back at the bottom. this works perfect, I just need to add the copy and paste/ammend section

Comment: Copy what to the end row?

Answer (score 0):

So something like this?

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim SrchRng As Range
Dim SrchStr As String
Dim pasteRow As Long

Set SrchRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B5000")
SrchStr = InputBox("Please Enter Number")
pasteRow = 1

    For Each cell In SrchRng
        If cell.Value = SrchStr Then
            cell.EntireRow.Copy (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet8").Range("A" & pasteRow).EntireRow)
            pasteRow = pasteRow + 1
            cell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the tips. I managed to piece it together and came up with the following.

Any hints on adding Paste Special (values) ?

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim c As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim SrchRng As Range
Dim SrchStr As String
Dim lastRow As Long





On Error GoTo Err_Execute


Set SrchRng = Sheets("Incubate").Range("B8:B5000")
SrchStr = InputBox("Please Enter Lab Number")
lastRow = Sheets("Fridge").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1

   For Each cell In SrchRng

   If cell.Value = "" Then
    Exit For
    End If

  If cell.Value = SrchStr Then
       cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Fridge").Range("a" & lastRow)
       cell.EntireRow.Delete

  End If

Next cell

Range("C5499:F5499").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C5499:F5500"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("C5499:F5500").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
Range("B8").Select
Exit Sub
Err_Execute:
MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```